# Coldfusion / XML Error

Tags: xml, coldfusion, bluedragon

I'm using Open BlueDragon since it's what my web hosting company use - plus it's open source.

I'm trying to read a YouTube feed using XML, and I keep getting the following error:

```
value [media:group] is not a number
```

My code is:

```
<cfhttp url="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Shuggy23/favorites" method="GET" />
<cfset xml = XmlParse(#cfhttp.FileContent#) />
<cfoutput>#xml.feed.entry["media:group"]["media:thumbnail"].XmlAttributes.url#</cfoutput>
```

I think it worked before unless my mind was playing tricks on me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Douglas

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - that code works perfectly fine on CF9, BlueDragon specific I suppose. what if you tried a different set of data - might lead to a clue:

```
#xml.feed.entry["gd:comments"]["gd:feedlink"].XmlAttributes.href#
```

If that fails as well I would suspect either the quote syntax or the colon notation, then try the BlueDragon docs & user forums.

Sorry I couldn't help more.

-sean

Answer (score 0):

This work on BD if you change your reference to xml.feed.entry[1]["gd:comments"]["gd:feedlink"].XmlAttributes.href.  Note that I've specified WHICH entry node you mean.  CF is clever enough to work out you were meaning the FIRST "entry" node (is that what you meant?).  BD is a bit more literal... it sees an array of "entry" nodes, so you need to specify which element of the array.

This simplified code demonstrates it:

```
<cfflush interval="1">
<cfxml variable="x">
    <a>
        <b><c>d</c></b>
        <b><c>e</c></b>
    </a>
</cfxml>
<cfoutput>x.a.b[1]["c"].xmlText: #x.a.b[1]["c"].xmlText# (OK on both platforms)<br /></cfoutput>
<cftry>
    <cfoutput>x.a.b["c"].xmlText: #x.a.b["c"].xmlText# (OK on CF only)<br /></cfoutput>
    <cfcatch>
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
        <cfdump var="#x#">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

HTH

Comment: Just FYI, I've raised a bug for this: http://code.google.com/p/openbluedragon/issues/detail?id=371; and put it on the radar over on the OpenBD google group too (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openbd/HzsHj41QHTA).  There's been no response to it yet, but they're usually very quick to fix things.